# How to use multiple regex patterns to tokenize string

Tags: java, regex, string, tokenize

I have to tokenize string s. s may have an alphanumeric, a closed and opened parenthesis and a hyphen. If it has an unknown character tokenizer needs to spout an error. Each of the elements should be tokenized e.g

String `aa (b - d)`

Token 1 -> `aa` (Alphanumeric)

2-> `(` (Open Parenthesis)

3-> `b`  (Alphanumeric)

4-> `-`  (hyphen)

5-> `d`   (Alphanumeric)

6-> `)`   (Closed parenthesis)

In addition, there is a condition that the hyphen and alphanumeric can ONLY have ( , ) or space (newline, tab etc) around it.

So `aa(d-b)` should throw an error.

My process here was to compile multiple patterns (relating to the above) and store them along with their code (i.e alphanumeric, hyphen, closedparen, openparen)

Then for every string, I go through the list of patterns (each of which is appended with ^) and try to match. If i find a match, i remove the token from the string and start again till the string is empty.

Since ( and ) are tokens and will be removed from the string after being found, how do I check for a subsequent alphanumeric or hyphen having the correct element before it. I know there are some convoluted ways to do this (store the previous match etc) but I was wondering if there was a simpler way.

Comment: show us what you've tried already.

Answer (score 0):

You're not gonna like this, but the easiest way to do this is to use a lexer like JFlex or ANTLR.
You will need need to set up a jflex file but after you've got that made it's really easy to tokenize strings.